# Creating a website in PhpStorm and I'm having trouble checking a database variable

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two functions, one to check whether a user is logged in, and another to check if the user is an admin. I also have a User database with one column named `user_lvl`, which displays fine if I output all the user data.

The problem I'm having is that with the admin function it doesn't seem read anything.

Here is the two functions code:

```
define('USER_LEVEL_ADMIN', '1'); 

    // check whether a user session is active, return true if yes, else return no
function isLoggedIn() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// check whether user has required user level to access admin privileges, return true if yes
function isAdmin() {
    // check if a user is in a session, then check if the users user_lvl is equal to 'USER_LEVEL_ADMIN
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] && USER_LEVEL_ADMIN == $_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']) {
        return true;
    }
    else {                      // works if you reverse true and false, else this is broke
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is where it is being called:

```
      <?php if (isLoggedIn() ) : ?>
            <?php if (isAdmin() ) : ?>
                <div>
                    <a href="adminPanel.php">Admin Panel</a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div>
                <a href="myAccount.php">My Account</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

It displays 'My Account' but not 'Admin Panel'. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That would happen if this `<?php if (isAdmin() ) : ?>` returns false.

Comment: It should not be returning false though, it should return true. I've tried messing with the code in different ways but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is ment for testing and identify which function is gives this output

```
<?php 

function isLoggedIn() {
    return true;
}
function isAdmin() {
    return false; // change it to true to see Admin Panel. You need to check the condition in this function.
}


if (isLoggedIn() ) : 
    if (isAdmin() ) : 
    echo '    
    <div>
        <a href="adminPanel.php">Admin Panel</a>
    </div>';
    endif;

    echo '
    <div>
        <a href="myAccount.php">My Account</a>
    </div>';
endif; 
?>
```

The `isAdmin()` condition looks fine, You may echo out the session variable and crosscheck.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 3 checks in the `if` statement is failing (returning false):

1. **isset($_SESSION['userId'])** *basic isset check*
2. **$_SESSION['userId']** *not sure what we're looking for here but this needs to result in boolean true*
3. **USER_LEVEL_ADMIN == $_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']** *authorized privilege check*

All 3 need to be true for the `if` to succeed.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] && USER_LEVEL_ADMIN == $_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']) {
        return true;
    }
    else {                      // works if you reverse true and false, else this is broke
        return false;
    }
```

I suspect the `if` is false due to this: `define('USER_LEVEL_ADMIN', '1');` which creates the named constant `USER_LEVEL_ADMIN` with a STRING value of `'1'`. Then, in your `if` statement you compare it to `$_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']`. Please check the variable type of `$_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']`. You can drop this line in your code to check that:

```
echo gettype($_SESSION['userId']['user_Lvl']);
```

It of course would need to match the type of `USER_LEVEL_ADMIN` which is `string`.

Comment: @McFlurry - did you get this figured out?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I haven't got it working yet no, I tried what you suggested and it returned 'Null' so I'm going to figure out why that is.

Comment: I have managed to get the result to be read correctly. current problem now is that the variable type is an array, and the function doesn't seem to check it correctly.